# How to use "with" construction in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var home = {}
home.table={}
home.table.width = 100
home.table.length = 200
home.table.weight = 20
home.table.material = "wood"
home.table.color = "brown"
```

How can I use structure `with (object) {code}` right to get something like this?

```
var home = {}
with (home) {
table = {}
table.width = 100
table.length = 200
table.weight = 20
table.material = "wood"
table.color = "brown"
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to alias a variable in a local scope? Functions work well for that.

Comment: I will say shortly : DON'T use WITH in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should read this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).  Quoting from that page:

> Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source
>   of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Con"
>   paragraph in the "Description" section below for details.

and also:

> Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict
>   mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose
>   properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

---

Secondly, if I were writing your code, I would do it like this:

```
var home = {};
home.table = {
    width: 100,
    length: 200,
    weight: 20,
    material: 20,
    color: "brown"
};
```

or, the whole thing can even be done in one JS literal:

```
var home = {
  table: {
    width: 100,
    length: 200,
    weight: 20,
    material: 20,
    color: "brown"
  }
};
```

---

Here's an example using a temporary variable (as recommended as a substitute for `with` by MDN) would be this - though in this case I would prefer the above format:

```
var home = {};
home.table = {};
var table = home.table;
table.width = 100;
table.length = 200;
table.weight = 20;
table.material = 20;
table.color = "brown";
```

Comment: Why not `var home = { table : { width : 100, length : 200 } };` ?

Comment: @OrangeFox - temporary variable example added to my answer, though in this case, I would prefer the one above it.

Comment: @Tibos - if you want max brevity, you can certainly nest the definition like that all in one JS literal.  Sometimes that is appropriate, sometimes it is not as readable - it depends upon context not provided here.  My aim here was to answer the question about alternatives to using using of `with` which only has to do with the declaration of the table object.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create properties in an object without specifying the object. Create the property first, then you can use it inside the `with` block:

```
var home = {};
home.table = {};
with(home) {
    table.width = 100;
    table.length = 200;
    table.weight = 20;
    table.material = "wood";
    table.color = "brown";
}
```

Using `with` is not recommended, though. It makes for confusing scope, and is disallowed in HTML5 strict mode.

You can use object literals to create the same object with even less code:

```
var home = { table: { width: 100, length: 200, weight: 20, material: "wood", color: "brown" } };
```